# Trying to understand memory-mapping with C++ in Linux environment

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, c++, memory-mapped-file

I've been tasked at worked to explore memory mapping to see if we can utilize it.

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept and how to write the code. I've been trying out the code in the following video and blog post, but I'll go over my steps here as well so it's easy to recreate. I'm working in C++ (gcc version 11.2.0) on a Linux system

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7E9piHcfr4

https://bertvandenbroucke.netlify.app/2019/12/08/memory-mapping-files/

Here's my code
`write_mmap.cpp`

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  // reading
  int file_read = open("test.dat", O_RDONLY, 0);
  // writing
  int file_write = open("test.dat", O_CREAT | O_RDWR,
                      S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);
  posix_fallocate(file_write, 0, 4096);

  char *buffer = reinterpret_cast<char*> (mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, file_write, 0));

  for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
    // Change each upper-case A to lowercase in the file
    if (buffer[i] == 'A') {
      buffer[i] = 'a';
    }
  }
}
```

And `test.dat` looks like this

```
Name,marker1,marker2,marker3,marker4
barc1,AA,AB,BB,--
barc2,AB,AA,BB,--
```

After running the commands

```
g++ write_mmap.cpp
./a.out
```

I see that `test.dat` has been changed to

```
Name,marker1,marker2,marker3,marker4
barc1,aa,aB,BB,--
barc2,aB,aa,BB,--
```

Which is what I was going for. I'm just unsure about a lot of things here
Firstly, Is `test.dat` a memory-mapped file? I see it in the filesystem when I `ls` in my directory, but is it in virtual memory somewhere? If so, is there some way that I can figure out where in the virtual memory it's stored?

Why is it that it was originally a text file when I wrote it, but it becomes a binary file after the script is done with it - when I open the file with `nano`, I see

```
Name,marker1,marker2,marker3,marker4
barc1,aa,aB,BB,--
barc2,aB,aa,BB,--
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
```

I'd also like to get some things cleared up about the memory mapping

1. This file is in RAM right now, right? Will any program (regardless of language used) be able to read from those portions of memory?
2. Is there some way to set "bookmarks" in this file. So that if I want the computer to start reading the file from a certain portion, I can tell it to read from address A to address B?

Comment: Does this help? [How to tell if a file is memory-mapped?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/309533/86440)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This file is in RAM right now, right?

No, the file is not in RAM. Portion of the file is in RAM. The second parameter to `mmap` requests a size of a memory segment used for mapping the file. The last parameter of `mmap` is a location inside the file. So in your example, you are mapping 4Kb starting from the beginning of the file. If the original file 4097 byte - the last byte would not be mapped. You can use `mremap` to move to a different block in the file.

And if you want to know where the memory is - just look at the return of `mmap`. Your variable `buffer` is exactly the pointer to some place in process' memory where the file is mapped to.

> Will any program (regardless of language used) be able to read from those portions of memory?

Yes. But it is a little more complicated.

First of all, if you do a `mmap` and then `fork` - the child would inherit the pointers and will have access to the exact same memory.

Second, if another process (regardless of language used) decides to map same file and same block in the file - it will have access to the same memory but it would be mapped into address space of that process. In other words - the two processes can still fight over file contents, but pointers to the same bytes would be numerically different.

And do not forget, that you can have a mix of sizes and offsets - 1st app maps 4Kb file from offset 0. Another maps 1Kb of the same file but from offset 1024. So only one 1Kb block would be contested. And such mix can be very complicated... And to solve this (or make it easier for memory management) we have "pages". Which come in play as a requirement that offset have to be a multiple of page size.

> Is there some way to set "bookmarks" in this file. So that if I want the computer to start reading the file from a certain portion, I can tell it to read from address A to address B?

No, no bookmarks. But 6th and 2nd parameters to `mmap` effectively do that - Address *A* is the last parameter and address *B* is last+second parameters to `mmap`.

BTW, you do not need to open file for reading. It is redundant in this case. You now have two file descriptors pointing to the same file, but you ignore the one which is for read only. Not a crime, but potential memory leak.

The bunch of `^@` you see when you open file in `nano` is a result of `posix_fallocate`. This function ensures that the file is of expected size for `mmap`. Technically, you do not need to call `posix_fallocate` if you sure that file is large enough to fill the segment requested by `mmap`. But if your file is too small - `posix_fallocate` enlarges it. So you now have a 4Kb file with the beginning filled with old data, and the trail filled with zeros (`^@` - representation of the 0 byte in `nano`)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!
I'm having a har d time understanding this still
If I do `std::cout << "Address of file is " << reinterpret_cast<void *>(buffer) << std::endl;`, I get a different address for `buffer` each time. But since buffer is pointing to the file, shouldn't it be pointing to the same address each time?
And what do you mean that I have two file descriptors? Which are the two in my code? Is there some Linux command I can use to see the file in RAM?
Sorry about the onslaught of questions. This is quite a bit more complicated than I thought it was going to be haha

Comment: No, it is not pointing to a file. It points to a memory block. That memory is part of memory belonging to the process. The numerical value of the pointer is a process' segment plus offset in that segment. And of course it would be a different value each time you start process anew. Just because the OS will put the process in a new segment. You need to read on "memory management" for better explanation

Comment: You have two descriptors: `int file_read` and `int file_write`. The first one is redundant.